# Bracket at end of 2 dimensional Array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, cout

Im printing a 2d array here but i want to format it to print like this.

```
[1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9]
```

My problem is printing the brackets.

```
   cout<< "[";
    for(int i = 0; i<numrows(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < numcols(); j++)
            cout << GetData(i,j) << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "]" <<endl;
```

But it prints like this.

```
[1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
 ]
```

Should i make an if statement that says if its the last one to print it?
Whats a good approach for this. Maybe im just blinde im so sleepy.

Comment: That's not your real code. The code you've given us would not add any line breaks after one row is printed.

Comment: You might find some use in the [pretty printer](http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/).

Comment: Oops wrong code. let me update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't output `endl` for last row:

```
cout<< "[";
for(int i = 0; i<numrows(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < numcols(); j++)
    {
        cout << GetData(i,j);
        if (j < numcols() -1)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }

    if (i < numrows() -1)
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
cout << "]" <<endl;
```

Comment: This puts a space at the end between the number and bracket.

Comment: Yeah but i dont get the concept between the -1

Comment: see my updated answer.  it means if not the last element, output `" "`, if not last line output `endl`

Answer (score 2):

Only print newlines when there is another line that follows:

```
if (i != numrows() - 1) { cout << endl; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    cout << "[";
      for (int nRow = 0; nRow < 3; nRow++){
        for (int nCol = 0; nCol < 3; nCol++)
        {
            if(nRow!=0)
            cout <<" "<<GetData(i,j) <<" ";
            else
            cout<<GetData(i,j) <<"  ";
        }
        if(nRow!=2)
        cout<<endl;
    }

cout << "\b]" <<endl;  // backspacing so that there is no space b/w 9 and ]
```

Comment: Ahh i had no idea a backspace existed!

Answer (score 0):

try This.
Output
| 1 2 3 |
| 3 4 5 |
| 3 4 2 |
| 2 3 1 |

```
int main()
{
    int arr[4][3];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Value:";
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout<<"The Values you entered are..."<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"|  ";
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<"|";
        cout<<endl<<"|  ";
    }
    cout<<"\b\b\b\b ";
    getch();
}
```